# Media Query Bootstrap Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to include a text animation on my website. I found a script that simply shuffles through phrases of text at a set interval. I really like the effect. The only issue I am having with it is on mobile. My understanding of media queries and bootstrap is lacking but I feel like this could be a quick fix. Basically on mobile the text which fits perfectly fine on one line on a desktop does not fit on one line on the smaller screen. This causes the phrase to go onto a second line which in turn makes the "container fluid" to grow which creates this jerky annoying effect.

What I want to do is either lock the "container-fluid" on mobile so that it does not jump or get larger or have it so the font size on mobile phones is slightly smaller so everything fits on one line as it does on desktop.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <section class="bg-primary" id="about">
    <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">


                <h1 id="textslide"></h1>           

                <h1 id="secondaryHeading">Get Shattr.</h1>


            </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

This is the script that runs the text animation:

```
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#textslide").html(quotes[i]);
        if (i == quotes.length - 1)
            i=0;
        else
            i++;
    }, 1.5 * 1000);
```

I understand that this is a CSS issue, but I cannot get the media query correct,

I tried calling #about under a media query:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {

#about{

    font-size:12px;


    }
```

This did not fix it though... if anyone follows that and can point me in the right direction in regards to either controlling the "container" so it would stay static will the text went to a second line or just to make the font all fit on one line on the mobile that would be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `#texslide` instead of `#about`.

Answer (score 0):

For a mobile device you should use this breakpoint.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #about{
    font-size:12px;
  }
}
```

It's a default xs breakpoint in bootstrap.

It says to apply the class if the device width is less than 767px.

Answer (score 0):

**Zcarpman**, Like how **yuyokk** showed you, how you need to use `max-width:`.
You also need to target the `<h1>`.
Try using this...

```
<style>

#about h1{
    font-size:26px;
}    
@media(max-width:768px) {
#about h1{
    font-size:12px;
}
}
</style>
```